# Высоко нагруженный сайт

Tags: python, asp.net, java

Добрый день,
На чем писать сайт ,в котором используется сложная логика ,при этом важна скорость ?
Python,Java,asp.net?Php в этом списке нету.
Мне сказали "Скорость: С++ Сложная бизнес-логика: С#, Java Простые сайты быстро: PHP"

Comment: Каежтся мне, если бы ты знал эти языки, ты бы сам решил, на каком языке писать что-то.

Comment: Пишите на том, что лучше знаете. В процессе разработки либо текущей скорости будет достаточно, всё равно потом придется переписать. Все переписывают. К примеру твиттер или эмакс (вроде 4 раза с нуля).

Но скорее всего либо Вы переоценили проект, либо свои силы.

Comment: рекомендованное чтение по вопросу сравнения языков (ссылку на русский перевод что-то не могу найти): [Is C++ better than Java? (or C#, C, Objective-C, JavaScript, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Haskell, FORTRAN, Pascal, Ada, Smalltalk, or any other language?)](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#lang-comparisons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Язык программирования редко является самым медленным звеном в веб-приложении (если только ваше приложение не будет заниматься тяжёлыми математическими расчётами). Гораздо чаще скорость работы веб-приложения зависит от производительности базы данных и скорости операций ввода/вывода (как сетевого, так и дискового). Ещё всё сильно зависит от архитектуры самого приложения. Язык программирования не играет особой роли, сайты, держащие тысячи подключений в секунду пишут и на Python, и на Java, и на ASP.NET. Поэтому выберите те технологии, которыми лучше всего владеете и сосредоточьтесь на архитектуре.

Comment: Верно, что для большинства проектов язык играет далеко не первую роль *по сравнению* с другими факторами, например: соответствие функционала и доступного времени способности людей, которые его реализуют. Хотя для некоторых приложений лучше сразу Erlang использовать, чем в очередной раз OTP по частям мастерить на Питоне. Или снизить затраты на сервер в 2 раза за счёт переписывания ключевого сервиса на Go.

Answer (score 2):

Серьёзные, масштабные, высокопроизводительные приложения из мейнстримовых языков лучше писать на C# или Java. В вебе они самые популярные после PHP среди крупных сайтов. Технологически языки родственные.

На скриптовых слабо типизированных языках (Python, Ruby, PHP) разработка может идти шустрее, но вы заплатите скоростью. PHP здесь выделяется как язык, для которого много готовых решений — если вы собираетесь воткнуть готовый движок с минимальными изменениями в коде, то, скорее всего, выберите его. Если писать руками, то лучше Python, Ruby. Если любите JavaScript, то можете попробовать NodeJS. Но это на любителя.

Если у вас будут узкие места с перемалыванием чисел и тому подобным (что маловероятно для сайта, но мало ли), то их отдельно можно оптимизировать на более близких к железу языках: C, C++.

Скорее всего, вы вообще уткнётесь по скорости не в язык, а в запросы к БД. Это уже другой вопрос.

В целом, если у вас возникает такой вопрос, то вам рано заниматься оптимизацией. Напишите на том, что вы лучше знаете — получится лучше. Если встанет вопрос производительности, то простор для оптимизаций широкий на любом языке, в крайнем случае можно и переписать (если вы не наработали кодовую базу масштабов Фейсбука).